# The relation between the effective sample size and the model dimension (the effective size of parameters)

Tags: statistics, bayesian

What is the relation between the effective sample size $n$ and the model dimension (the effective size of parameters) $p$ in Bayesian model selection? Or is there any articles talking about this?

I guess $p$ is a function of $n$, intuitively since if we have more data points, larger $p$ will give a better model fit. But in terms of the information criteria, like AIC, BIC, WAIC, WBIC, DIC etc., I only found papers that talking about the model dimension $p$ related with these citeria, so how does the effective sample size effect these criteria?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Effective sample size relates to the data; model dimension relates to the number of parameters. The two are unrelated.

In [Spiegelhalter et al’s (2002)](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1467-9868.00353) well known paper “Bayesian measures of model complexity and fit”, the connection is reiterated:

“...definition of p * that was derived by Moody (1992) and termed the ‘effective number of parameters’. This is the measure of dimensionality that is used in NIC ( Murata et al., 1994 ).”

To clarify, I say model dimension and [effective] sample size are unrelated because you could theoretically calculate the model dimension a priori (before you collect any data) using a point estimate of the prior distribution. Of course a posterior point estimate is more desirable, which is conditioned on the observance of data, and therefore you would justified in saying $p$ is a function of $n$.